# #2006 Error: MySQL server has gone away when I try to drop a database

Tags: mysql, mamp

I'm using MAMP and I already created a "my.cnf" file inside Applications/MAMP/conf with a high value of max_allowed_packet. But, everytime a try to drop my database, this error occurs, all tables are deleted, but the schema isn't. How can I force my db to be dropped?

Comment: I would say some internal error occurs within MySQL when you try to drop the database, which crashes MySQL, hence the error message. Check out MySQL's error log, perhaps it contains a hint.

Comment: Thanks, I cheked out the log and the error was a table missing index on foreign key...

Comment: I would add this as an answer (just provide a bit more details around how you found out, what was in the log, and what you did to resolve the issue) and accept your own answer. This may come handy for other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the file mysql_error_log.err in Applications/MAMP/logs. The problem was a missing index on a foreign key in a table. I added this index and the problem didn't happen again.